# Problems with .ssh directory in windows XP

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to use (git) ssh with SSH keys in windows XP using Powershell.

When I run ssh it always attempts to get the keys and known hosts from a location that doesn't really make sense in a windows context.

i.e.

```
prompt> ssh -vvv user@server
...
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /.ssh/id_rsa
...
prompt>
```

In windows 7 this behaviour seems to cause the `.ssh` directory to be created or read from the `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. However, in Windows XP this does not seem to be the behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem is caused / related to the way environment variables work in Powershell and Windows.

Utimately it would seem that (git) ssh is picking up the value of `$env:HOME` which in powershell is different to the value of $HOME.

In Windows 7 this value can be set with the command `setx HOME /c/Users/james`. If you wanted to set your home location to be a drive (i.e. `z:`) you would have to use the trailing slash else setx will assume it is a flag. i.e. `setx HOME /z/`

This will have effect in the next Powershell window that you open (but not in the current one)

In windows XP `setx` is not always available (it is on SP2 and SP3) and if you read the Microsoft documentation you might believe that `setx` is just a short hand for `reg add` but this is actually a lie.

If you use the command `reg add HKCU\Environment /v HOME /t REG_SZ /d "/c/Documents and Settings/james/"`

While this updates the registry in seemingly the same way as `setx`. The changes are not avilable in (Git) ssh until after a logoff / login cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify it directly:

```
 ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```